# Inserting a caption makes my table behave weirdly

Tags: tables, captions

I'm trying to insert a caption into the following table:

```
\newpage
\begin{tabularx}
{\textwidth}
{ | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm} 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X| }
 \hline
 \textbf{Weak-Form Violations} & \\
 \hline
 Momentum Effect  & One way of discerning trends in stock prices ... \\
 \hline
Return Reversal & Although there is some evidence of momentum in ...\\
\hline
\textbf{Semi-strong Anomalies} & \\
\hline
```

Which, currently looks like this:
[image]

For some reason, when I try to insert a caption, it messes up my table badly. I've tried multiple places to insert the `\caption`, this one messes up my table the least, the others completely destroy it's structure. Can someone explain me how to correctly caption this table?

```
\newpage
\begin{tabularx}
{\textwidth}
{ | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm} 
  | >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X| }
 \caption{Table 1}
 \hline
 \textbf{Weak-Form Violations} & \\
 \hline
 Momentum Effect  & One way of discerning trends in stock prices ... \\
 \hline
Return Reversal & Although there is some evidence of momentum in ...\\
\hline
\textbf{Semi-strong Anomalies} & \\
\hline
```

Comment: \caption doesn't go *inside*  a tabularx, move it outside and put a table environment around everything.

Comment: And again please provide examples that other can copy and test as is. Here we have to add stuff in order to just test your code.

Comment: @daleif, I would but I'm using a `\documentclass{clv3}` as style - and that style is defined in a .cls file of 2065 lines. It's a template that I got from school. I don't think you'd want me to add a file of 2000+ LOC - How would I make it so that it runs as is?

Comment: First check if the issue is available in a simple document using `article` and a few relevant package. That way you can rule out any unavailable custom classes.

Comment: @daleif - I will next time. Thanks for helping me understand how to use the site.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer This solved my issue! TYVM.